Java Generics Super Keyword Behvior
I want to understand the behaviour of bounded wildcard '? super Type' in java. I have written below code and I am not able to understand why the first case works and second case does not work
public class Testing {
    public void print(List<? super Number> list) {
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testing t = new Testing();

        // First Case
        List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add("kk");
        l.add(1);
        t.print(l);

        //Second Case
        List<? super Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Object o = new Object();
        list.add(o);
    }
}

In First case, a list of objects 'l' gets copied into a type 'List<? super Number>' during the method call. But second case gives compiler error as object can't be added into the type 'List<? super Number>'. Why ?

Imagine you had a List<Serializable> - that should (IIRC; it's been a while) satisfy List<? super Number> but you can add arbitrary objects to it.

side note: gets copied into a type is wrong, nothing is copied anywhere, it is cast, and only reference to object is passed to function

complementing first comment, in second case it could just be a List<Number> (? is Number) - obviously you cannot add an Object to it
